# Is there a way to move the scroll to the column that has been searched

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the datatable code to make a table on my search page. I was wondering if there was a way to move the scroll horizontally to the column that has been searched. So for example, if the table had two-column, the first column called first name and the second column called last name and someone searched the last name, then the scroll moves the whole table so the second column is the first column that is seen.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#searchResult').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 20,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        "sScrollX": '100%',
        "scrollY": '400px'
    });

});
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind I changed the tags around. This really has nothing to do with Ruby, Rails, SQL,or databases. It's all client side, meaning it's Javascript. And more specifically it's a jQuery plugin called Datatables